# Access Variables In Different Html files?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 HTML files, and 1 JS file

```
index.html
index1.html

main.js
```

in `main.js` i have a global object like as follows

```
var global={
  a:''
}
```

from `index.html` I assigned a=10;

```
<script>
  global.a=10;
</script>
```

from `index1.html` when I tried to access the value i am getting `undefined`

```
<script>
   alert(global.a);
</script>
```

Is there any way That I can access that value with out Sessions/localstorage ?

Comment: Cookies will work.  Do not forget that when you go from one page to the next, your entire JavaScript is taken down and obliterated.  You have to stash the data somewhere.

Comment: Why don't you want to use localStorage?

Comment: Javascript works based on the DOM elements, it means, on the HTML delivered to the user. That will make out of scope anything from different pages.

Comment: Design your app properly, and consider using a single-page approach in case. In any other, use either sessions or query params, but in 2014 I would go with the first mentioned choice.

Comment: There are lots of solutions for your problem. What is happening on the server side? Can you merge those two html in one and then using javascript go from one to the other, even with a nice animation? If the case is two static HTML files and no server side access I would consider using the URL, but if you do not want to expose your code, maybe cookies are a good way to go, but I'm still think that merging the two files would give you a more comfortable environment to work with a single Js code

Comment: Take a look at [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) if you want a system which automatically handles browser-to-browser and browser-to-backend synchronization for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set it as a variable in the URL query string, and then read the query string for the value.

Something like:

```
index.html?variable=value
```

Another option would be to set a cookie with the variable key/value, and then read the cookie when the page loads.

```
document.cookie=variable + "=" + value;
```